# How to create Carousel like control?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I need a "Сarousel like" control in my windows phone 7 APP, there will be list of images and I need to switch them like items in Pivot. What control should I use? Pivot is very similar, but I need footer in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Pivot` control where you hide the headers, I blogged about a simple solution to this problem here:

[A Windows Phone 7 Slide View with Page Pips](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/12/a-windows-phone-7-slide-view-with-page-pips/)

You can add your fixed footer under the Pivot control as follows:

```
  <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#EAE5C7">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:PivotLocationView Source="{Binding ElementName=pivot}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

    <controls:Pivot Margin="0,-30,0,40" 
                    x:Name="pivot">
      <controls:PivotItem>
      ...
      </controls:PivotItem>
      <controls:PivotItem>
        ...
      </controls:PivotItem>
      <controls:PivotItem>
        ...
      </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>

    <!-- your fixed footer goes here -->
    <Grid x:Name="footer" Grid.Row="1">
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can there be other controls below pivot? I need some buttons there not to be listed with images.

Answer (score 1):

If you(or anyone else stumbeling into this question hunting for fancy UI elements) want it a bit more fancy you could alternatively use the [Silverlight Flow Layouts Library](http://slflow.codeplex.com/) which is a very powerfull carousel system with a dedicated WP7 binary. I have not used this on WP7 yet my self, but I have used it with WPF and it both looks good and performs well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the control from this [Codeplex project](http://silverlightcarousel.codeplex.com/) Silverlight Carousel Control
 and hope it does not use any non-WP7 features.